# send large text to server using html form hidden value

Tags: java, javascript, html, forms

HI all

I need to send an dynamically generated html to server using html form, html can be bigger size at present it is 1MB

I m sending an dynamical generated html to server using form hidden input field. at server side exception is : too large content..

The dynamically generated html is used to generate pdf and generated pdf will send back to browser in same request of response.

How to handle bigger size html which is generated dynamically.

Please help me out.

Thanks
kumar kasimala.

Comment: what range of size's are we talking about when you say "bigger"?

Comment: What is it that you want? Do you want to post a html form to the server or a pdf? Do you want to generate the PDF on the server and sent that back to the client? In that case you can use a servlet to handle the post and use a reporting library (like JasperReports) to generate PDF.

Comment: Yes, what you describe is not very clear. Please clarify the process you want to implement (you can use bullet points to avoid long phrases).

Comment: @In Sane
size is about 1MB, when i send that via post request, exception : too large content..

Comment: I m sending an dynamical generated html to server using form hidden input field. at server side exception is : too large content.. 

The dynamically generated html is used to generate pdf and generated pdf will send back to browser in same request of response.

Comment: HI all just now edited it, sorry for misleading question

Comment: Who is generating that page, BTW?

Comment: Question: Why cant you use an html file input?

Comment: its not possible to use html file. we are generating a html content  using javascript, if user want to make  as pdf, we have to send that html to server to generate pdf, and get back to browser to download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use asp.net you can do like below:

In Web.config file, add

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100000" executionTimeout="360"/>
```

under `<system.web>`

Comment: I m using java at server side

Answer (score 0):

**Split it.**

1. Try to split the content to multiple inputs. Your implementation might have problem with that... but that's not too probable
2. Split the content to multiple requests and send them with AJAX. Collect the responses and be sure to send it in the right order (not all requests at once). Last request should confirm it's the end and load a page returning the pdf

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit on your problem and hit upon this page which says that the post size is set by the server in its configuration and can be changed by resetting it - http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5400480

Answer (score 0):

If you use java:

Use servlet post method to transfer the data to the server

```
<form method="post" name="sample_form" action="/xxx">
....
</form>
```